# JQuery CSS: I need to add a css style class to my button in the table.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a css style class to my button which is in the table.

There are 2 problems I am facing:

1) If i add the color/class using

```
    document.getElementById('btn11').style.color="blue";
```

the blue color is only applied to the first row button.

2) How can I add Google material design button in var?

```
        ex: var buttonVar = ('<md-button id="btn11">'+"Clicking"+'</md-button>');
```

Plz advice

```
    success: function (data) {
     var trHTML = '';
     $.each(data, function (i, item) {

         if(data[i].test_progress=="Complete")
         {  

         var buttonVar = ('<button id="btn11">'+"Clicking"+'</button>');
         }
         else
             {
         var buttonVar = ('<button id="btn12">'+"Stoping"+'</button>');
             }


         trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i].test_type + 
         '</td><td>' + data[i].device_id + 
         '</td><td>' + data[i].make + '&nbsp'+data[i].model+
         '</td><td>' + data[i].stack_name +
         '</td><td>' + data[i].suite_name + 
         '</td><td>' + data[i].test_progress + '<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'+data[i].tests_run+'/'+data[i].total_tests+
         '</td><td>' + data[i].start_time + 
         '</td><td>' + data[i].end_time +
         '</td><td>' + buttonVar +
         '</td></tr>';
        });
     $('#test1').append(trHTML);

      document.getElementById('btn11').style.color="blue";
//document.getElementById('btn11').style.className='md-primary md-raised';
        // $('btn11').addClass('action-button');

          $(document).on('click', '#btn11', function(event) {
             alert("The paragraph was clicked."+ i);
            });

          $(document).on('click', '#btn12', function(event) {
             alert("The paragraph was not clicked."+i);
            });

 }
```

Comment: 1) You can't have more items in your HTML with the same `id`. For more than one item, you have to use a `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use more than one element with the same id per page. For this kind of functionality  give your button the class `btn11` and `btn12` and use this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn11').style.color="blue";
```

To update the color of all buttons with that class.

A material design button is just a normal button (`<button>`) or link (`a`) with custom css styles. Using the materialize theme you can do it with

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Stuff</a>
```

For example, but it all depends on the css framework you use.